# Extract text between a string and new line character (/n) using regex

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a text file and want to extract texts between two strings ("StartString" and "EndString" in below example) if a substring exists between those two strings. There may be multiple such instances in the text file. After this, I want to extract first occurrence of the "someID" in those multiple instances. For example,

**Example text file (text_data)**

```
 
ghguy  hja  StartString I want this text (1) if substring 1 lies in between the two strings someID: abcd_efgh
ghsjgsajhgj someID: dgfshgj
EndString bhghk [jhbn] xxzh StartString I want this text (2) as a different variable if substring 2 lies in between the two strings ghdsdjsagdsh someID: fhcb7hkhb
ghjxcgsydgsdycgsjxcskcsal someID: ghyoet_fstj
EndString ghjyjgu
```

**Output:**

first_variable = I want this text (1) if substring 1 lies in between the two strings someID: abcd_efgh
ghsjgsajhgj someID: dgfshgj

second_variable = I want this text (2) as a different variable if substring 2 lies in between the two strings ghdsdjsagdsh someID: fhcb7hkhb
ghjxcgsydgsdycgsjxcskcsal someID: ghyoet_fstj

first occurrence of someID in first_variable = abcd_efgh

first occurrence of someID in first_variable = fhcb7hkhb

**I tried extracting the first variable as:**

```py
target1 = 'StartString'

target2 = 'EndString'

pat1 = '{}(.+?){}'.format(target1,target2)

pattern = re.compile(pat1, flags=re.DOTALL)

first_variable = pattern.findall(text_data)
```

I have no clue how to extract first occurrence of the someID in each instance. Can anyone help me out in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

`StartString[\s\S]*?someID:\s*(\S*)\b[\s\S]*?EndString`

Look for `someID:` in between `StartString` and `EndString` and capture the word until word boundary is encountered.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/D0wpGd/4)

Comment: Thanks for providing the regex pattern. Just to clarify, I am looking for a list containing the texts just after "someID:" when it appears first time in the text between 'StartString' and 'EndString' and ignore all the second, third, fourth... occurrences of "someID"

Comment: This is exactly what the pattern above does. The capture group contains the expected strings. Refer to the attached demo.

Comment: already did that. Thanks. Can you provide a sample code how to generate a list of those IDs?

Comment: @vaibhavpandey That is a separate question. But before asking, you should read about how to access capture groups in regex.

Comment: thanks @CinCout. I will try to do it by myself. Appreciate your help.